# how to modify standalone-full-ha.xml in jboss

Tags: java, xml, jboss7.x, redhat

I am modifying the standalone-full-ha.xml file present in standalone/configuration directory in  JBoss EAP 6.0.1, but when I am restarting my application server, the standalone-full-ha.xml changes are getting reverted back to the previous state.

What is the procedure of modifying the standalone-full-ha.xml file ?? Do I need to change any other configuration before modifying this file ??

Please advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you modifying the file while the server is still running?

Comment: thanks for quick response, but yeah I was doing it while server was running, now I am able to modify the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jboss can save changes to the config file at runtime. Normal procedure also makes the Jboss save the setting file back to disk at shutdown. (As a side note, in domain mode your deployments also get written into the config files so you can accually open them and see what you have deployed right now. If you then restart your Jboss it will read the config file and proceed with a redeployment of the applications you had deployed before restart)

**That means that the config file you edited got overwritten at shutdown.**

> I generally edit the config file at a separate location and then move
>   it to the config directory. I would actually encourage you to also
>   version control this setting file since it over time probably will
>   contain lots of small changes.